# Prevent screen push down when field focused in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, focus, field

We have a search field on top of our page. When the search field gets focused the page itself pushed to down. This is happening only in some iOS devices. I was able to replicate this in iPhone 13 Pro max, and further analysis we could find the same in other sites as well. I have attached a video here which shows the exact issue. Please provide a solution if anyone faced similar issue.

Video Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1liSDhI1WrwobjaExSVntOyVkYfXkiXsL/view?usp=share_link

I have tried to add .focus() when the search button clicked. Some times the field doesn't shows cursor pointer, but the keyboard was present.

Thanks in advance
Sreeraj S